# Random occurrences of Failed: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1 when running protractor tests

Tags: node.js, protractor

My protractor test cases randomly fail with this error message:

Failed: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1

I have gone through the resources and tried all the suggested solutions:

- Upgraded protractor
- Ran webdriver-manager update
- Upgraded chromedriver version but the issue seems to exist.

This particularly happens when I try to run all the e2e tests together.

Below is the specific versions that Im using for my project:

- node - v9.2.0
- protractor - Version 5.4.1
- ChromeDriver 2.42.591088

Please help.

Thanks,
Neeraja

Comment: yeap, that answer below worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you using async/await in your tests?

Can you try applying patch as specified below from the same folder which contains the 'node_modules' folder by executing 'node patch.js'?

patch.js file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var httpIndexFile = 'node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js';
fs.readFile(httpIndexFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err)
    throw err;
var result = data.replace(/\(e.code === 'ECONNRESET'\)/g, "(e.code === 'ECONNRESET' || e.code === 'ECONNREFUSED')");
console.log(`Patching ${httpIndexFile}`)
fs.writeFileSync(httpIndexFile, result, 'utf8');});
var chromeFile = 'node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js';
fs.readFile(chromeFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err)
    throw err;

var result = data.replace(/new http.HttpClient\(url\)/g, "new http.HttpClient(url, new (require('http').Agent)({ keepAlive: true }))");
console.log(`Patching ${chromeFile}`)
fs.writeFileSync(chromeFile, result, 'utf8');});
```

Please see original post here - 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4706#issuecomment-393004887

Comment: Yes I am using async/await in my tests. Will try this workaround and see, thanks a ton :) !!