# Iterate until matching text is found

Tags: protractor

I am writing a test which should iterate until a partial matching text is found . Once found , it should do some thing.  Here is my code.

```
let getName = await $$('.button').getText();
if (getName === 'New name') {
 // do something here

}
```

My test doesn't iterate even though there exists a matching name. It should also consider partials tests, for instance New name 1.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Why do you have 2 closing parenthesis ?

Comment: Thanks for finding. I corrected it @executable

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a shot in a dark due to lack of details in your question, but I'll try to guess your problem.

`$$().getText()` returns array of strings, thus your code must be

```
let names = await $$('.button').getText();

for (let i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
  if (names[i].includes('New name')) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

But when you `await $$().getText()`, and there are more than ~10 elements, be ready to face this error [Random occurrences of Failed: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1 when running protractor tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197202/random-occurrences-of-failed-econnrefused-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-when-r)

Actually, I must include another guess here based on an assumption you'll need to interact with the first element that matches condition

```
let $newNameElement = await $$('.button').filter( $elem =>
  (await $elem.getText()).toLowerCase().includes('new name');
).get(0);

// do whatever you want with your $newNameElement
```

Comment: lmk if any problems

Comment: Thanks for this. But the if statement still doesn't execute if use includes. But If i write  if (name[i] === 'New name')  it works. This way I can only validate one string. I want to match against multiple values

Comment: when you find those elements, what exactly do you want to do with them? In a nut shell, let $$newNameElement = await $$('.button').filter( $elem =>
  (await $elem.getText()).toLowerCase().includes('new name');
) should return you all elements that you're looking for. so you can interact with each of them through forEach()